# Running celery worker from script and concurrency

Tags: python, concurrency, celery

I have a wrapper script that starts a worker, but I don't understand how to limit the amount of concurrency. I tried to read the celery code, but for me it's very hard to see how they do it.

My code:

```
from celery.bin import worker as w

my_worker = w.worker(app=app )
options = {
  'loglevel': loglevel,
  'queues': [service,],
  'hostname': hostname,
  }
my_worker.run(**options)
```

I don't really know how to add the concurrency to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code just use `cmd` `celery`:

```
def start(self,datas):
    queue = datas['queue']
    # check if exists with app.control.inspect().active()
    all_workers = self.active(datas).keys()
    if all_workers:
        return None
    #return os.getcwd()
    a="celery multi start %s_worker -A celeryserver  -Q '%s' --concurrency=1 -l  DEBUG" % (queue, queue)
    sys.argv = a.split()
    from celery.bin.celery import main
    try:
        main()
    except SystemExit as exit:
        return exit.code
```

for your code, add `'concurrency': 1` to your `options` (**It should work, not tested**), but I suggests you to use `main` with `sys.argv` just like I do.
 Because it can auto parse `sys.argv` into `*args, **options` with `Command.handle_argv` and call `__call__` which call `self.run()` (just like you do,but more compatibility and easy).

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find the concurrency option in the worker.run function, but it works.

Comment: All `options` not list in `run function`, will be received by `**kwargs`.

Comment: Yup, that's what I understood. For an outsider it is just difficult to figure out which arguments are really used I guess. Thanks again. It works now.

Comment: What is `datas`?

Comment: Can you post the whole class, not sure what `self.active(datas).keys()` does.